# Why do this code only delete the first rows of the datagridview?

Tags: c#

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Index = 0;
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        string delete = dataGridView1.Rows[Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("delete from Contact_List where Name='" + delete + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully");
            filldata();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record not Deleted....Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
    con.Close();
```

why do this code only delete the first rows when i selected the second rows?

Please help!!

Comment: Because _Index = 0_ ?

Comment: you assigned Index = 0 before executing the code; what else you would expect?

Comment: But in the other article , it shows that it delete the row that selected. So how do i change it? how do I make it work that it delete the selected row?

Comment: Thanks , It work now.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `Index = 0` in the first line.  So, every time you call that method, it always deletes the first row, which is Index 0.

If you want to remove the selected row, you have to use, `SelectedIndex`.  Consider below sample code:

```
string delete = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Index` was initialized with `0` and the value will not get updated during the execution, so each time the first row get Deleted. so what you want to do is, update the variable `Index` with current row index like the following:

```
Index= datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
string itemToDelete = dataGridView1.Rows[Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
// this will be the `Cells[1]` value at the selected index
```

Comment: Is there anyway to not delete the 2 information that have the same name with the code above?